# Why not using WHERE clause after LEFT Join doesn't throw any exceptions?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I recently noticed that while using LEFT JOIN's, if you forget to use WHERE clause you don't get any error message, lets you build and run it. But your code after the WHERE clause doesn't work either.

Check this sample:

```
SELECT 
     [C].Id AS Id
    ,[C].Code AS Code
    ,[C].[Desc] AS [Desc]
    ,[C].DateCreated 
    ,[C].UserCreatedId, [U].Username AS UserCreatedUsername, '(' + [U].Username + ') ' + [U].Firstname + ' ' + [U].Lastname AS UserCreatedFirstnameLastname 

    FROM rel_MerchantCurrency [MC]
    LEFT JOIN Merchant [M] ON [MC].MerchantId = [M].Id
    LEFT JOIN Currency [C] ON [MC].CurrencyId = [C].Id
    LEFT JOIN [User] [U] ON [MC].UserCreatedId = [U].Id

    AND [M].Id = @MerchantId

    AND [MC].Deleted = 0
    AND [M].Deleted = 0
    AND [C].Deleted = 0
    AND [U].Deleted = 0
```

This code can be build without a problem. However, it never checks the last few lines. So it doesn't work properly. But this code below:

```
 SELECT 
         [C].Id AS Id
        ,[C].Code AS Code
        ,[C].[Desc] AS [Desc]
        ,[C].DateCreated 
        ,[C].UserCreatedId, [U].Username AS UserCreatedUsername, '(' + [U].Username + ') ' + [U].Firstname + ' ' + [U].Lastname AS UserCreatedFirstnameLastname 

        FROM rel_MerchantCurrency [MC]
        LEFT JOIN Merchant [M] ON [MC].MerchantId = [M].Id
        LEFT JOIN Currency [C] ON [MC].CurrencyId = [C].Id
        LEFT JOIN [User] [U] ON [MC].UserCreatedId = [U].Id

        WHERE [M].Id = @MerchantId

        AND [MC].Deleted = 0
        AND [M].Deleted = 0
        AND [C].Deleted = 0
        AND [U].Deleted = 0
```

This works perfectly, because I am adding the "WHERE" clause.

My question is: Why don't I get any error message for the first code? I believe because the code runs all the AND clause at the bottom with the last LEFT JOIN line. But shouldn't it be working anyway? What would you recommend to avoid this situation since there are no exception thrown? I recently changed a lot of my Stored Procedures for LEFT JOIN's, and I assume most of them has this problem,  and I don't want to experience it again in future.

Comment: You need to review joins.  Maybe you think the second works perfectly but you changed all the left joins into inner joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first section of code is syntactically correct, so you don't get errors, but it doesn't make sense. As you haven't used a `WHERE` clause, all of the `ANDs` at the end are being applied to the `LEFT JOIN` between tables [U] and [MC].

You may not be aware, but you can put multiple conditions into a join, so it is quite valid to specify something like

```
LEFT JOIN [User] [U] ON [MC].UserCreatedId = [U].Id AND [MC].DateCreated = [U].DateCreated
```

rather than the equivalent statement of

```
LEFT JOIN [User] [U] ON [MC].UserCreatedId = [U].Id 
WHERE [MC].DateCreated = [U].DateCreated
```

So your SQL is basically specifying that

```
LEFT JOIN [User] [U] ON [MC].UserCreatedId = [U].Id
AND [M].Id = @MerchantId
AND [MC].Deleted = 0
AND [M].Deleted = 0
AND [C].Deleted = 0
AND [U].Deleted = 0
```

Since you are applying conditions on the join which relate to tables [M] and [C], they are being ignored as they cannot affect the join between tables [U] and [MC]. And because they are being treated as conditions of the join between [U] and [MC], they are not being applied to the joins that you want.

If you wanted to, you could move the `ANDs` that are related to the Joined tables into the Joins themselves. This would make your code look like

```
SELECT 
     [C].Id AS Id
    ,[C].Code AS Code
    ,[C].[Desc] AS [Desc]
    ,[C].DateCreated 
    ,[C].UserCreatedId, [U].Username AS UserCreatedUsername, '(' + [U].Username + ') ' + [U].Firstname + ' ' + [U].Lastname AS UserCreatedFirstnameLastname 

    FROM rel_MerchantCurrency [MC]
    LEFT JOIN Merchant [M] ON [MC].MerchantId = [M].Id AND [M].Deleted = 0 AND [M].Id = @MerchantId
    LEFT JOIN Currency [C] ON [MC].CurrencyId = [C].Id AND [C].Deleted = 0
    LEFT JOIN [User] [U] ON [MC].UserCreatedId = [U].Id AND [U].Deleted = 0
    WHERE [MC].Deleted = 0
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact, why didn't I thought of putting them there in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

In your first query, it is interpreted as

```
LEFT JOIN [User] [U] 
   ON (
           [MC].UserCreatedId = [U].Id
       AND [M].Id = @MerchantId
       AND ...
      )
```

(note the brackets)
That is why it is not a syntax error when you forgot that `WHERE`. You just restrict the join instead of the final results.

Comment: Thanks, that's the only logical explanation as I suspected. However, why it still works, there is no "[M].Deleted = 0" or "[C].Deleted = 0" identified in the last LEFT JOIN clause? I feel like I should be getting an error like "M.Deleted is not related with User table" etc.?

Comment: [ON - Specifies the condition on which the join is based. The condition can specify any predicate](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634(v=sql.105).aspx). So apparently even "whether it makes sense for the JOIN or not"

Comment: Yeah, apparently.. Can we consider it as a bug then? Or it makes sense in some way?

Comment: I don't consider it a SQL bug. You certainly could want to join on multiple conditions.

Comment: @NecatiHakanErdogan - it may help you to understand that at the point at which the final `LEFT JOIN` is being considered, what's on the left-hand of the join *isn't* the `Currency` table, nor the `Merchant` table, nor even the `rel_MerchantCurrency` table. What's on the left-hand side is the result set formed by combining those tables using the previous `JOIN`s. And so it's perfectly valid to be referencing columns from *any* of those tables. (Or, another way, thinking of joins as always between two *tables* is wrong. It's between two *result sets*, but in the *common* case those are tables)

Comment: Hello Damien, I got it, it makes sense of course, but then again, the result is wrong. I mean the ".Deleted = 0 " lines doesn't work at all. Which means the sql engine considers only the last LEFT JOIN clause while running the "Deleted = 0" rows. Not the combined tables of all of them.